# Construct the name of the method to be called at runtime

Tags: java, design-patterns, reflection

I'm learning Java and I'm fairly new to this. Here is my problem with some pseudocode:

```
public void objectCaller(int objectNumber) {

   switch(objectnumber) {

     case 1:
     object1.setFill(color.RED);
     break:

     case 2:
     object2.setFill(color.RED);
     break;
     .
     .and so on

    }
}
```

Is there a way to replace it in a way with something like that?

```
public void objectCaller(int objectNumber) {

   (object + objectnumber).setFill(color.RED);

}
```

It is not a concrete problem. I was just thinking about if it is possible to assemble the object names.

Comment: What is the type for `method1` and `method2`. Are they objects of the same class?

Comment: Without a doubt there is a problem with your design and you should probably be using inheritance and polymorphism. You need to expand a little on what you are trying to do.

Comment: @70g50 Take a look at my answer for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that by [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/), but for this case is clearly overkill.
What about this approach?: Store your objects in an array (or a List) and then use the index to access the required one.
Note that I'm assuming that all the objects are of the same class or are least they have a parent-child class relationship, as @ChetanKinger pointed in the comment below.

```
public void methodCaller(int methodNumber) {
   myArrayOfObjects[methodNumber].setFill(color.RED);
}
```

PS: In fact, you are trying to compose "object" names, not methods names. In that case you would really need to use the Reflection API

Comment: This will only work if `method1` and `method2` are siblings or in a parent-child relationship.

Comment: Good point, updating the answer! I Assumed it automatically because they seem to share the same method, but actually that does not have to be always true

Comment: I feel that just because one can use reflection doesn't mean they should. The specific example provided by the OP could better be implemented using the Strategy and Factory pattern. See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

There are three approaches you can use to solve the problem (Reflection is the last option I would recommend) :

**Option 1 : Employ the [Strategy](http://www.oodesign.com/strategy-pattern.html) pattern**

If `method1` and `method2` are not objects of classes that are related. Employ the `Strategy` pattern as follows :

```
  public interface Filler {
     public void fill(Color color);
  }
```

Create two classes that `fill` colors differently :

```
 public class FloodFill implements Filler {
     public void fill(Color color) {
         //fill using flood fill algorithm
     }
 }

 public class QuickFill implements Filler {
     public void fill(Color color) {
        //fill using quick fill algorithm
     }
 }
```

You can then use the `Map` approach explained below :

**Option 2 : Use a HashMap**

Assuming that `method1` and `method2` are related either through a common parent or through a parent child relationship, create a `HashMap` and prepopulate it with method1 and method2 objects :

```
 Map<String,Filler> methods = new HashMap<>();
 FloodFill method1 = new FloodFill();
 QuickFill method2 = new QuickFill();
 map.put("FloodFill",method1);
 map.put("QuickFill",method2);
```

You can then change the `methodCaller` method to :

```
public void methodCaller(String method,Color color) {
     methods.get(method).fill(color); 
}
```

The client code can then look like this :

```
methodCaller("FloodFill",Color.RED);
methodCaller("QuickFill",Color.GREEN);
```

Using a `HashMap` instead of a basic `array` or a `List` allows you to associate meaningful names to your method calls. The `HashMap` is kind of a `Factory` for objects. The `String` constants used as the key for the `Map` can be defined as `enum` instead.

**Option 3 : Use reflection :**

This is not something I would recommend for this particular case but if you have to, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string) answer on how to achieve this trough reflection.